# Commas and word phrasing

Tags: grammar, sentence

The Revolution only ended with the death of the leader, Ji Tai, after whom, Pol Zara, took over the leadership in 1978.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: If you take out the parts set off by commas, does the sentence still make sense?

Comment: No. What are you getting at?

Comment: If the revolution ended after the death of Ji Tai, how can it (something which no longer exists) have been taken over by Pol Zara? Many things are wrong with this sentence, not least of all the parenthetical use of *Pol Zara* which is actually essential to the sentence.

Comment: @user585380, because it's a clue that you shouldn't use commas in one of the two cases.

Comment: It should really read something like this: *The revolution ended with the death of its leader, Ji Tai. After his death, Pol Zara took over leadership of the government.*

Comment: But what did Ji Tai lead? The revolution or the government? The quote says "the leader".

Comment: @WeatherVane Good point. It's ambiguous. I made an assumption, but it's not clear.

Comment: Thank you so much, Jason. Also, all the other people as well, I have realised the sheer stupidity of my statement. I will amend it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> The Revolution only ended with the death of the leader, Ji Tai, after whom Pol Zara took over the leadership in 1978.

Take out the commas before and after *Pol Zara* and this looks and sounds right. Ji Tai gets commas because he substitutes the phrase "the leader", but Pol Zara does not because he does not substitute anything.

As for the meaning, I assumed that after the revolution had ended with said death, Zara, related or not, came under leadership whether the revolution had succeeded or not. I'm assuming it had not.